# Get the dimensions of the selected object at Inkscape [python]

Tags: python, height, width, selecteditem, inkscape

I am writing an Inkscape extension in Python and I need the dimensions of the selected object.
How can I get the height and width of the object I select at Inkscape?

Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Inkscape from inside the extension, compare how other Inkscape extensions do it.

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/0.92.x/share/extensions/dimension.py#L118

Or you could use simpletransform.py's functionality (less exact, doesn't work with text):
https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/0.92.x/share/extensions/simpletransform.py#L206